# select form_for helper for parent association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've the following models:

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :room


  #some validations

  validates :room, presence: true
end
```

And

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reservation

  # some validations
end
```

What I'm trying to do is show the select options of room_id and validates the Association, not the Foreign Key.

So, I have this form helper select for `Reservation`:

```
<%= f.select :room_id, Room.all.map { |room| [ room.code, room.id ] }, required: true %>
```

The problem is when I try to save, the validation of Room is called and says that the

> "Room can't be blank"

How can I do this? My permitted params on ReservationController are:

```
params.required(:reservation).permit(:room, ...) #... = other params
```

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you add `room_id` to the strong params? Also can you please post your reservation/room controller create action?

Comment: @HarrisonLucas
The validation pass if I change :room to :room_id permitted params.

How can I validate if the Room exists? the Validation: `validates :room, presence: true` doesn't do this?

There's a better way to create the selection? Something like "simple_form" using `f.association` by [plataformatec](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

Comment: see my answer for a more detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

The Params should be like:

```
params.required(:reservation).permit(:room_id, ...)
```

and if you would like to verify whether a room is valid or not,You can do this:

```
if Room.where(id: @reservation.room_id).present?
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to save the reservation to the room, you need to add `room_id` to your permitted params, and not just `room`.

E.g.

```
params.required(:reservation).permit(:room, ...) #... = other params
```

Now if you want to validate that a reservation definitely has a room you could do something like this in your controller

```
def create
  room = Room.find(params[:room_id] # or whatever that param is
  reservation = room.reservations.build(room_params)

  #... rest of method here
end
```

This will ensure that a reservation always has a valid room. You can then also (as an extra saftey measure) do

```
validates_presence_of :room_id
```

On your reservation.

Hope this helps!